# java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, selenium

I have this error when I ran this test. For the previous test file, it ran perfectly.

```
@DataProvider(name = "login")
public Object[][] loginData() throws BiffException, IOException {
    Object[][] arrayObject = testDataXls.getExcelData(
            System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\resources\\testdata\\Input_TestData.xls",
            this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    return arrayObject;
}
```

Here the getExcelData I used

```
public String[][] getExcelData(String fileName, String sheetName)
        throws BiffException, IOException {
    String[][] arrayExcelData = null;

    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fs);
    Sheet sh = wb.getSheet(sheetName);

    int totalNoOfCols = sh.getColumns();
    int totalNoOfRows = sh.getRows();

    arrayExcelData = new String[totalNoOfRows - 1][totalNoOfCols];

    for (int i = 1; i < totalNoOfRows; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < totalNoOfCols; j++) {
            arrayExcelData[i - 1][j] = sh.getCell(j, i).getContents();
        }

    }
    return arrayExcelData;
}
```

I don't know why it didn't perform as the previous test file. And the error is highlighting on the `Object[][] arrayObject = testDataXls.getExcelData(`

Comment: Does the excel file contains the data you are looking for?

Comment: Yep, I already solve it. I just change something in the method

Answer (score 0):

Your `testDataXls` instance is probably null. I suggest you to run this test case in debug mode and put a breakpoint on that line. Then inspect the `testDataXls` instance.

Comment: able to solve it. I use this method:

Object[][] arrayObject = testDataXls.getExcelData("C:\\Users\\eclipse\\selenium\\src\\test\\resources\\testdata\\Input_TestData.xls", "AppScenarios");